# Falha no WHERE ao associar uma coluna para consulta em uma view

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Estou passando alguns parâmetros para uma view onde preciso receber o retorno dessa consulta. Ao definir os filtros no Where da minha query, o retorno da consulta informa o seguinte erro:

> Nome de coluna 'competencia' inválido.

Sei que é falha minha de codificação, mas eu declaro no meu where as colunas para consulta

```
      public RelatorioDTO relatorio(DateTime compInicial)
    {
        // vw_relatorio: View 

        string query = "select cpfCnpj from vw_relatorio where competencia <= @compInicial";

        string myConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString();

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);

        SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

        SqlParameter parameter = dbCommand.CreateParameter();
        parameter.ParameterName = "@compInicial";
        parameter.Value = compInicial;
        parameter.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(parameter);

        dbCommand.Connection.Open();
        dbCommand.ExecuteReader();
        // retornar a consulta
    var retornoLista = new List<RelatorioDTO>();

        if (((SqlDataReader)(myReader)).HasRows)
        {
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                retornoLista .Add(FiltroRelatorio(myReader));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

        return retornoLista;
  }
```

Retornando item a item:

```
private RelatorioDTO FiltroRelatorio(IDataReader myReader)
    {
        var result = new RelatorioDTO ();
        result.CpfCnpj = myReader["CpfCnpj"].ToString().ToUpper();

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Considere usar dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter) ou simplesmente.

dbCommand.AddWithValue("@compInicial", compInicial ?? (object)DBNull.Value);

Comment: @compInicial sempre terá um valor definido ao realizar a consulta.

Comment: essa coluna existe na view? não há nenhum erro de digitação nela? inclua o código da query da view na pergunta